# Phpmailer для разных форм

Tags: php, phpmailer

есть форма с телефоном, именем и сообщение , и есть форма с одной лишь почтой.
что я должен сделать ,чтобы всё отправлялось именно с одного файла php.
тут уже всё настроено под первую форму
это форма в футере ,

```
<form id="message__form" class="footer__form" action="send.php"
   method="POST">
                 <input
                   name="name"
                   type="text"
                   class="input footer__input"
                   placeholder="Your Full Name*"
                 />
                 <input
                   name="phone"
                   class="input footer__input"
                   placeholder="Phone Number*"
                 />
                 <textarea
                   name="message"
                   class="footer__message"
                   placeholder="Message"
                 ></textarea>
                 <button class="button footer__button" type="submit">Send</button>
                 <span class="footer__info">* Required Fields</span>
               </form>
```

а это форма в другой секции

```
<form id="email__form" action="send.php" method="POST" class="subscribe newsletter__subscribe">
        <input
          name="email"
          type="email"
          class="subscribe__input"
          placeholder="Your email address"
        /><button class="subscribe__button">Send</button>
      </form>
```

Ну и настройки самого Send.php
знаю что надо добавить $email = $_POST
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Просто укажите в `<form action="">` ваш обработчик, а в нем проверяйте - если есть входящие данные, то берите их, в противном случае определите значения по умолчанию.

Comment: Это то я задал , а как мне в в самом send.php это указать , чтобы две разных формы с него работали. А то в таком случае с формы где один email приходят сообщения с формы где телефон

Comment: `send.php` не важно, сколько там форм. Его задача - принять данные, если они есть, и отправить письмо. Напишите ваши формы и обработчик здесь, только текстом, не картинкой. Сейчас непонятно, в чем проблема.

Comment: Скинул, я просто не понимаю как создать второе сообщение в php файле, что бы с разных форм отправлялось разное сообщение .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если ничего не трогать в формах, то вы можете просто проверять, к примеру, значение в `$_POST['email']`. Если оно есть, значит, отправлена форма с email'ом, если нет, значит, первая.

```php
<?php

// в зависимости от пришедшей формы формируем сообщение:
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    // если есть что-то в $_POST['email']
    $body = 'User mail: ' . $_POST['email'];
} else {
    // если нет, отправлена форма с телефоном и пр.
    $body = 'name: ' . $_POST['name'] . ' <br />';
    $body .= 'phone: ' . $_POST['phone'] . ' <br />';
    $body .= 'message: ' . $_POST['message'] . ' <br />';
}

// ну и тут отправляйте его куда хотите:
echo $body;
```